# Issue reading screen pixels for color detaction

Tags: andengine

I am making a game representing freehand drawing and sprites to animate when pass over it. So i have to use color detection and cause an event when the change in color is encountered by sprite on the screen from where it passes. For this i am using glReadpixel() passing RGBA_8888 and GLES20 version and recieve its value in Red Green Blue form but everytime it returns everything to be 0. Tried to change pixelformat and make many hit and trial but no sucess. Can you please help

My code:

`

```
ByteBuffer PixelBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4);
PixelBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
PixelBuffer.position(0);
int mTemp = 0;

 GLES20.glReadPixels(100, 100, 1,1,GLES20.GL_RGBA,GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, PixelBuffer);
byte b[] = new byte[4];
PixelBuffer.get(b);
Log.e("COLOR", "R:" + PixelBuffer.get(0) + PixelBuffer.get(1) + PixelBuffer.get(2));
```

`

Result
Logcat : COLOR R: 000.

I tried using non black background and have red color on screen coordinate provided.

Thanks in advance

Comment: GLES20.glReadPixels(100, 100, 1,1,GLES20.GL_RGBA,GLES20.GL_FLOAT, PixelBuffer); can you try that and tell me if it's ok ?

Comment: Apparently a lot of phone are not compatible with that, are you sure yours is ?

Comment: well i am not sure of it, my testing device is Samsung galaxy S. Can you tell is it compatible? If not, on which series of device should i test?

While using Cocos 2D it was working well in the same device